# Fixed Header without using hard values on body padding

Tags: css, user-interface, dynamic, navigation

Normally, to keep any body content from rendering underneath the fixed nav, I will add padding-top to the body element.

I do not like this because I have to either specify a hard unit value on the body padding, the height of the header, or both in order to be confident they will match up. I despise giving a header a hard-coded height, and then styling for each breakpoint becomes even more cumbersome, especially when I am building for a corporate site with lots of constantly changing business rules for their header with different conditions across different breakpoints.

How can I have a dynamically size fixed header that does not overlap with the body content without using hard unit values? I am not interested in using JavaScript, CSS only.

Here is a overly simplified example of what I am referring to: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have the body sit below the nav when the nav is fixed (and therefore out of the flow). My normal solution here is `padding-top` on the body as you say, but set it in a variable. Using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) would mean you can set the breakpoint based heights in the settings as one variable and then access once in your base layout styles. But as far as I'm aware, it's either magic numbers or JS.

Comment: If you wanted a hacky solution in which you have a dummy div that sits at the same place in the DOM has your fixed nav would appear logically if it were not fixed and then give it the same height as your nav.  This really isn't any better than using padding-top though.  In fact, it's probably worse

Answer (score 0):

In future CSS standard, you are able to set the height of the header as a variable and use it in `padding-top` of `body`.

At this moment, you may use different CSS preprocessors like SCSS, SASS, [PostCSS-cssnext](http://cssnext.io/) to achieve this goal.

Reference:
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/